# How do I parse Url with `&` sign in jquery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have following code in `common.js` file.

logic is if `HighlightTextBox` if data is not matching and `RemoveHighlightTextBox` if data is matching.

```
url  = /Services/GetAutoCompleteData?v=

name = My & Son

actualUrl = /Service/GetData?v=My & Son&eq=true

//debuge following js code and found above values
//here problem is because of `&` sign url gets disturb as `actualUrl is /Service/GetData?v=My & Son&eq=true`
//so after `&` sign url gets ignore by js (i.e Son&eq=true code)
//i have passes values `My & Son` but actually js parsing it as `My` so how do I parse my original URL with `&` sign ?

var div = $(this).closest("div");
var elem = div.find(":text");
elem.change();
var name = elem.val();
var actualUrl = url + name + "&eq=true"
var filter = $(this).attr("filter");
if (name == "") {
    div.find(":hidden").val('');
    return;
}
AjaxPostCall(actualUrl, filter, function (data) {
    if (data == null || data.length != 1) {
        HighlightTextBox(elem);
        div.find(":hidden").val('');
        return;
    }
    RemoveHighlightTextBox(elem)
    div.find(":hidden").val(data[0].Key);
    elem.val(data[0].Value);
});

function AjaxPostCall(actualUrl, extraParam, onSuccess) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: actualUrl, 
        data: extraParam,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) { if (onSuccess != null) onSuccess(data); },
        error: function (result) { }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  var actualUrl = encodeURIComponent(url + name + "&eq=true");
```

> **encodeURIComponent** Thisfunction encodes a `URI` component.
>
> This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the
>   following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

Comment: @ashuthinks Glad to help you. Whenever we're going for web service or web call, **encoding** is necessary.  I too faced a similar problem in `C#` where `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` came into rescue. So remember **URI encoding is mandatory** :)

Comment: You should only encode `name` don't encode the parts that aren't dynamic

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the parameter value with `&` using method [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) before appending to parameter string.

ex

```
encodeURIComponent('name = My & Son')
```